# ROS Installation on Kali Linux

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've knew ROS these days and I'd like to install in my OS, but I found nothing about it. My OS is Kali Linux Rolling Version. Is it possible to run the last ROS version on it?

I apologize if this kind of doubt does not fit in the forum's context.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259992/ros-installation-on-kali-linux/) by [inluxbdx](https://answers.ros.org/users/30127/inluxbdx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-04-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The closest thing to usable binaries for Kali would be the Debian packages for Kinetic. But since Kali is based on Debian Testing, not Stable (Jessie), I think it's unlikely that you'll be able to get them to work easily. Building from source might be easier, and with Kali's closeness to Debian *might* work. But again, version differences (such as changes in Boost version) may well prevent it compiling.

If you don't need the penetration testing capabilities of Kali, switching to Debian Jessie might be your best bet.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2